# How to set and verify state parameter with AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement `state` parameter with `aws-amplify`.

I am generating a random string and adding it to the hosted-ui url and after logging in I am getting the state value with the redirectSignIn. But I would like to know on how I can validate the state parameter values.

Right now I am manually storing the state value in session and on successful login checking if the values match in Angular app.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this using the `aws-amplify` module.